# I have no brothers or I have no brother?

Tags: grammatical-number, negation

Which one is correct and why?

> **A:** I want a potato!
>
> **B:** *We have no potatoes* **or** *we have no potato*.

Answer (score 0):

B's reply should be: We have no potatoes.

Typically (in English) when you have zero of something, the plural is used. This is unless the sense would require it, which is not the case here.